# Paste named vector R

Tags: r, paste

I would like to paste a named vector and a string. Is there a way to keep names?

```
named <- c(first = "text 1", second = "text 2")
description <- c("description 1", "description 2")
```

Expected result is:

```
setNames(paste(named, description), names(named))

>                first                 second 
"text 1 description 1" "text 2 description 2"
```

But it is redondant as the names are already in the vector. Is there an other way to preserve names without duplicating access to variables?

```
paste(named, description)

> "text 1 description 1" "text 2 description 2"
```

Answer (score 9):

You *can* use `[<-` to preserve attributes:

```
named[] <- paste(named, description)

                 first                 second 
"text 1 description 1" "text 2 description 2"
```

This solution has the disadvantage of messing up your existing `named` vector. You could avoid it with two steps:

```
x <- named 
x[] <- paste(named, description)
```

Or make a function:

```
foo <- function(x, y) setNames(paste(x, y), names(x))
foo(named, description)

                 first                 second 
"text 1 description 1" "text 2 description 2"
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It is really elegant. Slight imperfection, this way I have to affect the object first then use it as an argument to a function.

Comment: You could do `x <- named; x[] <- paste(named, description)`, but then that wouldn't be very elegant

Comment: Yes I have understood. But as an argument to `pickerInput` directly for example, I have to add an additionnal step of assignment before.